# Is there a commentary on tehillim that maps perakim to episodes in David's life?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, tehilim-psalms, commentaries

Sometimes it's fairly easy to tell when David is writing about a particular event such as

> לדוד בשנותו את טעמו לפני אבימלך

At other times it's less obvious, but you get a 'lightbulb moment' when someone points it out, e.g. Malbim says that Psalm 30 is about David Hamelech's teshuva being accepted after the sin with Batsheva. Are there any commentaries on tehillim, or on Shmuel for that matter which discuss chapters of tehillim in light of the events that inspired them?

Comment: I don't know of a commentary that *exclusively* does that, but as you've noted, sometimes the traditional commentators will show the connections.  (It should also be noted that many perakim were not written by David.)

Comment: I would be surprised if there were anyone who did that *exclusively* but I was wondering if there was someone who did that in such a way that it covered a large portion of David's life.

Comment: Some prints of Tehillim have brief headers before many perakim describing exactly that. For example, the standard Chabad Tehillim: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32596&st=&pgnum=29&hilite=

Answer (score 4):

Rav Moshe Eisemann wrote a book about Dovid HaMelech called "Music Made in Heaven" - the subtitle of the book is "some thoughts on Dovid Hamelech and Sefer Tehillim." He does not go systematically through Tehillim, but he uses Tehillim as a means of analyzing events in Dovid Hamelech's life. I think it could largely satisfy what you are looking for.

It's available [here](http://www.diggingdeeperjewish.org/kishinievbookdetail/music.htm), and unless something has changed in the past year, proceeds of book sales go to supporting an outreach Yeshiva.

Answer (score 2):

Artscroll interlinear Tehillim will cover most of it either in a short preface to each chapter or in the notes on bottom.